# Selecting the last entry in sql database for each id field

Tags: sql

Hi all I am using `SQL server`.

I have one table that has a whole list of details on cars and events that have happened with those cars.
What I need is to be able to pick out the last entry for each vehicle based on their (Reg_No) registration number.

I have the following to work with

```
Table name = UnitHistory
Columns    = indx (This is just the primary key, with increment) 
Transdate(This is my date time column) and have Reg_No (Unique to each vehicle) .
```

There are about 45 vehicles with registration numbers if that helps?

I have looked at different examples but they all seem to have another table to work with.
Please help me. Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH cte 
AS
(
     SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER
         (
             PARTITION BY Reg_No
             ORDER BY Transdate DESC
         ) AS RowNumber
     FROM unithistory
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: Thanks allot for the help. I am running the statement now and will keep you posted. Thanks again

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks guys, you saved me from a long agonising search.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the index and the transdatem and they are both incremental (I am assuming that a later date corresponds to a higher index number) then the simplest query would be:

```
  SELECT Reg_No, MAX(indx), MAX(Transdate)
    FROM UnitHistory
GROUP BY Reg_No
```

If you want all data for a known Reg_No, you can use Dd2's answer

If you want a list of all Reg_No's with thier data, you will need a subquery

Comment: MAX(indx) will return always the record with the highest number.

Comment: No, it will not. It will return the highest index within the group by.

Comment: I'm thinking the highest index within the group might not be the latest. Well, it will work if you assume the records are ordered by Transdate. I know the records order is not guaranteed. Am I wrong?

Comment: as long as the Transdate is inserted as the actual moment that the record is inserted and the indx is indeed incremental, the highest date should correspond to the highest index. But I agree that we do not have enough information to safely make that assumption, which i swhy i mentioned "I am assuming that a later date corresponds to a higher index number"
Ah, also, indx is just a normal field with auto-increment, not a generated index number from SQL. I agree the name is confusing :)

Comment: Thanks allot for the help. I am running the statement now and will keep you posted. Have chosen to go with the more detailed one as i will need the added info. Thanks again