# VB.Net MS-Access querying the latest entry depending on date

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, vb.net-2010

Here's the table below I am using in MS-Access.

[image]

There can be multiple entries for the same item but I need to get the value corresponding to the latest dated entry. For example considering the below dataset,

[image]

If I want to know what the closingStock for item 'XYZ' is, it should return 70 as that is the latest entry (as per date /dd-mm-yyyy). I am using ms-access and vb.net for this, which I am very much unfamiliar with and have tried using a max(date) etc, but access syntax/interface seems a bit weird to me now. Would appreciate any help. I would prefer to do this in vb.net code.

Comment: This post looks similar with your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19929969/selecting-the-last-entry-in-sql-database-for-each-id-field/19930052#19930052

Comment: similar ... sort of ... would be interesting to hear from redGREENblue, why the follow-up since he accepted an answer on the other post.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
SELECT Max(tblInventory.transdate) AS MaxOftransdate, tblInventory.item, Last(tblInventory.closingStock) AS LastOfclosingStock
FROM tblInventory
GROUP BY tblInventory.item;

Replace the tblInventory with whatever your table name is.  You can also replace the 'Max' with 'Last' if you prefer

Craig